# EntityFramework conflicting with another codebase - Migrations fail

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Disclaimer - I am new to the company, I didn't have any say in the previous codebase

I'm having a fun issue.  We have a very large web-based application, with its own database library (not using EF or Dapper or.. anything - literally a roll your own code-first framework).  This library removes any columns that are not in its models, which is obviously a pain.  Moving forward, I have directed my team to split any new modules out into their own service, whether a windows service, web api, whatever.  However, because of the amount of data these modules share, they are still using the same database as the web application.  In some cases, models from a new service are added to the web application so they can build a UI for it.

Here's where it gets fun - I just wrote a new service.  Using EF Code-first, I built my models as usual, and use migrations.  However, for example in UAT, the UI piece has already created SOME of the models, so my migration fails as the table / columns already exist, and as such it doesn't create the other models.  It just stops the migration completely.

It would be nice if EF could detect that things already exist, and just leave them alone and move on, but it doesn't seem to.  We've have already disabled the piece of the old library that deletes columns, as that was causing a huge issue.

So, main question is - can EF detect things that already exist, and simply move on, or what would your approach be?

(Note, the database is postgresql)

Comment: Always include a version number with your database.  This way as you do the migration you know which tables exist and which table do not exist.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, I've never had to use that before.  I've never had multiple solutions using the same database

Comment: Well now you have.  I is good practice to include version number in database design so as updates are mode your code is forward backward compatible.